# $L^2$ Correspondence Between Dirichlet and Neumann Domains

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^k$ be compact with smooth boundary, $T$ denote the trace operator to its boundary (i.e. a continuous extension of the restriction operator), and define the following subspaces of $L^2(\Omega)$:
$$\mathcal{D}_D=\{u \in H^2 \textrm{ such that }Tu=0\}\quad \textrm{and}\quad \mathcal{D}_N=\{u \in H^2 \textrm{ such that }T(\partial_nu)=0\},$$
the Dirichlet and Neumann domains, respectively. Does there exist a continuous bijection from $L^2$ to itself which restricts to a bijection from $\mathcal{D}_D$ to $\mathcal{D}_N$?

Some comments: I know that such a map exists if, instead of the Neumann domain, we consider functions which satisfy some APS boundary condition, see for example section 3 of [[BL]](https://arxiv.org/abs/dg-ga/9609001). However, the Neumann boundary condition requires information in a neighborhood of the boundary, so the methods presented in that paper don’t work. I can’t prove that no other way works though, but this example shows that we need to look at information which is more refined than simply considering the functional analysis perspective.

Answer (score -1):

Define $L$ as the  bijection which is continuous.

Let $k = 1$, $\Omega = [0,1]$

For $u$ continuous such that $u(0) = u(1) = 0$, define,
$$L(u) = \int_0^x u(y) \  dy $$

Hence we have,
$$T(u) = 0,T(\partial L(u)) = 0$$

This is also a bijection on continuous functions upto addition of constant functions.

Now extend this to $L^2[0,1]$ since continuous functions are dense in $L^2[0,1]$. The bijection follows from general version of Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

This can be tried to be extended to $k>1$ for $\Omega = [0,1]^k$ by using higher dimensional analogue of fundamental theorem of calculus.

For example, if we can extend the normal vector at the surface to a smooth vector $N(x)$ in $\Omega$ then define:

$$L(u) = \int_{0}^1 u(\gamma(t)) dt$$

$$Path \ \gamma(t) : \gamma(0) = a, \gamma(1) = x, \gamma'(t) = N(\gamma(t))$$
Pick shortest path,

For surjection, for function $u \in D_N$, choose $$w(x) = <\nabla u(x),N(x)>$$

$$L(w) = \int_{0}^1 <\nabla u((\gamma(t))),N(\gamma(t))> dt = u(\gamma(1)) - u(\gamma(0)) = u(x) - u(a).$$

So we have surjection upto a additive constant function.

But unfortunately $$D_N \supseteq L(D_D) \supseteq H^3 \cap D_N$$ upto additive constant functions. Not sure of equality in the first subset inclusion.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147714/discussion-on-answer-by-balaji-sb-l2-correspondence-between-dirichlet-and-neu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.